# Filter children in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I want to filter children in elastic search without changing the parent node, i have something like this data, and want to all games, but only "isVisible = true" members should appear with each game

```
{ 
"_index": "test", 
"_type": "Game", 
"_id": "1", 
"_source": { 
"gameName" : "test game",
"teamMembers" : {
    "id" : "2",
    "name":"John",
    "isVisible" : true
    },
{
    "id" : "3",
    "name":"emma",
    "isVisible": false
}
```

}
}

So, i want to get the above game as is but with only 1 team member (John)
i am using C#, and tried this:

```
var result = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<Review>, QueryContainer>>();
result.Add(a => a.Nested(n => n.Path("teamMembers").Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field("teamMembers.isVisible").Query("true")))));
```

but it didn't work.

Note: i am using Elastic search 5.

Comment: try using term query instead of match https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-query-usage.html

Comment: i tries like this: 
result.Add(a => a.Nested(n => n.Path("teamMembers").Query(q => q.Term("teamMembers.isVisible", true))));

but the same issue appeared: "All shard failed", i i remove this line, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
result.Add(a => a
                .Nested(n => n
                              .Path(p=> p.TeamMembers)
                              .Query(q => q
                                           .Terms(t=>t
                                                 .Field(f=>f.TeamMembers.IsVisible)
                                                 .Terms(true)))));
```